# Why google chrome does not cache search history?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am facing a strange behavior in the chrome that i didn't know how to fix it. when i surf between pages, i'v notified that Google chrome does not cache my searching history. look at below figure:
[image]

of worth to say that swiching between pages are being performed by `javascript` below function:

```
window.location.replace({URL});
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking or how it's related to asp.net!

Comment: That's the [whole point of `location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace). You're probably looking for [`location.assign(url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) or `location.href = url`

Comment: @phuzi because the framework i am using is asp.net may there is a configuration in webconfig

Comment: @blex what's difference but i will test it

Comment: Read the links I provided, they will explain it in far more details than I will :) The very first link explains the difference right at the top

Comment: @blex looks this is the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN docs for `location.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace):

> The `Location.replace()` method replaces the current resource with the one at the provided URL. The difference from the [`assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) method is that after using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) the current page will not be saved in session [History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History), meaning the user won't be able to use the back button to navigate to it.

[`location.assign(url)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) or `location.href = url` would probably be more appropriate to use in your case.

Comment: honestly i did test it but same result. lemme test it more

Comment: i did ctrl+F replace all location.replace to location.assign and cleared the cache but same problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using `window.location.assign('/my-url')`. Can you provide a minimal code example that does reproduce the problem?

Comment: yea sure. please wait a minute

Comment: window.location.assign(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/home.aspx");

Comment: i closed the broswer and restarted. it works now .thank  in advance

Comment: Oh ok, probably a local cache issue